# XServer.app Google Sing in: Update user data in iOS Swift

Tags: ios, swift, google-signin, xserver

I'm building an iOS app and need to allow my users to sign in with Google using [XServer](https://xserver.app)

I've downloaded and installed the SDK, created the OAuth credential on my Google Cloud Platform, and this is my code so far:

```
import GoogleSignIn

class GLogin: UIViewController, GIDSignInDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var googleButton: UIButton!
    var googleSignIn = GIDSignIn.sharedInstance()
    

    // Google Sign in button
    @IBAction func gSignInButton(_ sender: Any) {
        googleSignIn?.presentingViewController = self
        googleSignIn?.clientID = "My_Google_OAuth_Id"
        googleSignIn?.delegate = self
        googleSignIn?.signIn()
    }

}


func sign(_ signIn: GIDSignIn!, didSignInFor user: GIDGoogleUser!, withError error: Error!) {
           guard let user = user else {
               print("Google login cancelled.")
               return
           }
           
           // Get User info
           let password = user.userID ?? ""
           let firstName = user.profile.givenName ?? ""
           let lastName = user.profile.familyName ?? ""
           let email = user.profile.email ?? password + "@google.com"
           let profilePicURL = user.profile.imageURL(withDimension: 150)?.absoluteString
           let username = firstName.lowercased() + lastName.lowercased()
           let fullName = firstName + " " + lastName
           
           self.XSSignUp(username: username, password: password, email: email, signInWith: "google") { (results, e) in
           if error == nil {
               
               // I don't know what to do here...

           } else { DispatchQueue.main.async { print(e!) }
       }}// ./ XSSignUp()

    }
       
    func sign(_ signIn: GIDSignIn!, didDisconnectWith user: GIDGoogleUser!, withError error: Error!) {
           // Call your backend server to delete user's info after they requested to delete their account
    }
```

So, I can successfully retrieve a Google user's data, as well as register the user in the database, but I don't know how to update its full name and profile picture, so those columns are empty after performing the code above.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm the creator of XServer.app, you did a good job so far, so what you're missing is a bit of code to check out if your user already signed up with Google or he's signing in again. You also need to call the `XSObject()` function to add additional data to your database -> Users table.

So, in the space where you placed the comment:

```
// I don't know what to do here...
```

Try using this code:

```
 let resultsArr = results!.components(separatedBy: "-")
 let uID = resultsArr[0]
 let isSignInWithAppleGoogle = resultsArr[1]

 // Already signed up
 if isSignInWithAppleGoogle == "true" {
   print("User previously signed up") 

 } else {
   DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1, execute: {

     // Add data using the XSObject() function
     let params = [
       self.param(columnName: "tableName", value: "Users"),
       self.param(columnName: "ID_id", value: uID),
       self.param(columnName: "FL_profilePic", value: profilePicURL),
       self.param(columnName: "ST_fullname", value: fullName),
     ]
     self.XSObject(params) { (e, obj) in
       if e == nil {
         print("Google user just signed up!")
       // error
       } else { DispatchQueue.main.async { print(e!)
     }}}// ./ XSObject
   })

 } // ./ If
```

Please note that The `FL_profilePic` and `ST_fullname` column names must match the names you gave to your columns when you created them in the database.

For more info, you can check this article too: https://xscoder.hashnode.dev/google-sign-in-with-xserver-ios-swift